# My website won't scroll on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

This has bothered me for a long time. Since I updated my personal website, it didn't scroll on either Android nor iOS mobile devices. I'm not sure what is causing the problem - css, Javascript or something else? 
Here is the my website: http://anniedream.com
And here is a cleaner version of my website (I took out the parallel scrolling stuff..) http://anniedream.com/150703Preview01/

Hope someone can help me out. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi annie(from your site), as there is already an answer pertaining to your question I thought I'd bring this up: Several of your images on the site are over 500kb in size reducing your page load speed immensely. I recommend optimizing these and other images for web related use! https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization?hl=en

Comment: Wow thank you very much! There are tons of raster images on my site and they indeed are slowing down the page loading. I will look into the article and figure out how to optimize those images! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a JavaScript problem, try removing

```
    skrollr.init({
        forceHeight:false
    });
```

If this is not the culprit, try desactivating the overlay. Something "covers" your website with a fixed element or something detects the scrolling and can't deal with it.

Maybe you added some pop-up or overlay effects that still get rendered on mobile. Try removing it instead of using `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`.

Comment: After removing the "skrollr.init", my website can scroll normally on mobile devices now! Thank you very much!!!